# why did not show first value of $img by array_search()

Tags: php

```
why did not show first value of $img by array_search()
```

There is $img where are 4 values. I do not know why always do not    show first value of $img ($img[0]);    If I changed first value then  same problem. Please tell me where is the problem?

```
function auto_call(){
$img=array("png","jpeg","gif","jpg");
$arrt=array("txt","jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
for($j=0;$j<count($arrt);$j++){
if(array_search($arrt[$j],$img)){
echo $arrt[$j]."<br/>";
}
} 
}
auto_call();

//the result is:
jpg
gif
jpeg
```

Comment: PHP array starts with position `0` so when it hits in the first position, the `if` statement is evaluated as false.

Comment: simple use in_array instead of array_search

Comment: use in_array() instead of array_search(). Because array_search gives the position of the element in array but in_array specified that element is in array or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) like this:

```
if(array_search($arrt[$j],$img) !== FALSE){
```

From the documentation:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

Updated code:

```
<?php
function auto_call(){
    $img=array("png","jpeg","gif","jpg");
    $arrt=array("txt","jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
    for($j=0;$j<count($arrt);$j++){
        if(array_search($arrt[$j],$img) !== FALSE){
            echo $arrt[$j]."<br/>";
        }
    } 
}
auto_call();

?>
```

Comment: I agree with this answer just extending it. The `array_search` function returns `0` for the first position, but it's also value which is evaluated as `false`. PHP arrays starts with `0`!

Answer (score 0):

I hope help this code...

```
<?php
function auto_call(){
$img=array("png","jpeg","gif","jpg");
$arrt=array("txt","jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
for($j=0;$j<count($arrt);$j++){
if(array_search($arrt[$j],$img) !==FALSE){
echo $arrt[$j]."<br/>";
}
} 
}
auto_call();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

array_search always return index of search element.if it is not found then returns false.so we are using something like that for return all search element.

```
function auto_call(){
$img=array("png","jpeg","gif","jpg");
$arrt=array("txt","jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
for($j=0;$j<count($arrt);$j++){
  if(array_search($arrt[$j],$img) || array_search($arrt[$j],$img) === 0 ){
        echo $arrt[$j]."<br/>";  
  } 
}
auto_call();
```

Comment: check this one,it'll be work for you.in 'if' condition if array_search return '0' index then it to be false for 'if' condition and it'll go to else part.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** Simple use `in_array` instead of `array_search` . `in_array` return `true` if value present in array otherwise return `false` . `array_search` will return the `key` if value presented . if first value present  it will return `0` so if statement will `fail` here so simple use `in_array`

```
<?php
function auto_call(){
    $img=array("png","jpeg","gif","jpg");
    $arrt=array("txt","jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
    for($j=0;$j<count($arrt);$j++){
        if(in_array($arrt[$j],$img)){
            echo $arrt[$j]."<br/>";
        }
    } 
}
auto_call();

?>
```